# Android how to replace soft keyboard hints with searchview custom suggestions?

Tags: android, searchview, search-suggestion

**Situation**

I have a searchview where the user can search for an item located in a local sqlitedatabase and a list of suggestions will pop up while the user is typing. I do this using a MatrixCursor, the support library's SimpleCursorAdapter, and searchview.setSuggestionAdapter(). This works fine in portrait mode, but has a problem in landscape.

[image: Suggestion problem]

The problem is that instead of the desired custom suggestion appearing, android.database.Matrix... appears.

**Problem**

How do I get my custom suggestions to show up in landscape mode (either in the softkeyboard or anywhere)? I don't have the option of disabling the hints altogether because the user will be confused if they misspell the item and then expect the result to appear when it doesn't.

**Code**

Fragment.java

```
private void setUpSingleSearch(final Menu menu, final MenuItem singleSearchItem) {
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(singleSearchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            displaySuggestions(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void displaySuggestions(String query) {
    MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{BaseColumns._ID,
            RestaurantTable.Cols.NAME, RestaurantTable.Cols.ID});
    RestaurantListing restaurantListing = new RestaurantListing(getContext());
    restaurantListing.getRestaurantSuggestions(currListName, "Name", matrixCursor, query);

    setUpSearchViewSuggestions(matrixCursor);
}

private void setUpSearchViewSuggestions(MatrixCursor cursor) {
    String[] from = new String[]{RestaurantTable.Cols.NAME};
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.search_view_suggestions_list_item,
            cursor,
            from,
            to,
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the softkeyboard was in full screen mode. So I just used searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN).